# Show that the sum of the squares of 3,4,5 and 6 consecutive numbers can not be a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, sums-of-squares

$\textbf{Edit:}$
Thank you so far for the answers. I still do not understand how to prove that the sum of 6 consecutive squares is not a square.

I've tried ${6d^2+30d+55 \ne n^2 \Rightarrow 6(d^2 + 5d +9)+1 \ne n^2}$ and would somehow like to elaborate this, but (yet again) I get stuck.

Is is correct to say that ${6(d^2 + 5d +9)+1}$ is on the form
${6k+1}$? Because then I could possibly stop there, having

${6k+1 \ne n^2}$

Thanks!

${\rule{8cm}{0.4pt}}$

\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
I've gotten this far:

$\textbf{Sum of 3 consecutive squares}$

Rewrite of problem:

\begin{equation}
              \begin{aligned}
                  (d-1)^2+d^2+(d+1)^2 &\ne n^2\\
                  3d^2+2 &\ne n^2 \\
                  \label{p1_1}
              \end{aligned}
          \end{equation}
Assume ${n=d\cdot3+r}$, where ${r=0,1}$ or $2$.
Then,

\begin{equation}
n^2 \equiv_3 r^2 \equiv_3 0 \vee 1
\end{equation}

Conclusion:

Since ${r=2}$ in ${3d^2+2}$ and ${r=0 \vee 1}$ in ${n^2 \equiv_3 r^2}$ we have shown that
${3d^2+2 \ne n^2}$.

Question: Is my conclusion and reasoning valid and "good enough"?

$\textbf{Sum of 4 consecutive squares}$

Rewrite of problem:

\begin{equation}
              \begin{aligned}
                  d^2+(d+1)^2 + (d+2)^2 + (d+3)^2 &\ne n^2\\
                  4(d^2+3d+3)+2&\ne n^2\\
                  \label{p1_b}
              \end{aligned}
          \end{equation}

${\Rightarrow} {r=2}$.

Assume ${n=d\cdot4+r}$, where ${r=0,1,2}$ or $3$.
Then,

\begin{equation}
n^2 \equiv_4 r^2 \equiv_4 0 \vee 1
\end{equation}

Conclusion:

Same reasoning as in conclusion of sum of 3 consecutive squares.

$\textbf{Sum of 5 consecutive squares}$

\begin{equation}
               \begin{aligned}
                   (d-2)^2+(d-1)^2+d^2+(d+1)^2+(d+2)^2 &\ne n^2\\
                   5d^2+10 &\ne n^2\\
                   5(d^2+2) &\ne n^2\\
                   \label{p1_c}
               \end{aligned}
           \end{equation}

${\Rightarrow r=2 \vee 10}$ (is this correct?)

${n^2 \equiv_5 r^2 \equiv_5 0 \vee \pm 1}$

Conclusion:

Same reasoning as in conclusion of sum of 3 consecutive squares.

$\textbf{Sum of 6 consecutive squares}$

\begin{equation}
              \begin{aligned}
                  d^2+(d+1)^2+(d+2)^2+(d+3)^2+(d+4)^2+(d+5)^2 &\ne n^2\\
                  6d^2+30d+55&\ne n^2\\
                  \label{p1_d}
              \end{aligned}
          \end{equation}

Here I'm stuck.

I feel pretty unsure about all my reasonings and would therefore appreciate your help. Please, feel free to be verbose in your answers.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint) Try mod 7.

Comment: @C.Park When $d\equiv1$, $6d^2+30d+55\equiv91\equiv0\mod7$  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [It is never a square for $3,4,\dots,10$ consecutive numbers, due to mod arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208625/318073).

Comment: @nlantau - Right. Then you have $6(7k+1)^2+30(7k+1)+55\equiv 42\mod 49$

Comment: The sum in congruent mod 4 to the number of odd squares. So since squares the sum may be equal ( and therefore congruent) to are $0,1\bmod 4$ we have restriction on number of odd squares.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Would you guys say I've made sufficient "proof" for the other cases (3,4 and 5)?

Comment: No, case 5 is wrong. $5(d^2+2)\equiv 0\bmod 5$, which is a valid square. I don't know how you got $r=2 \vee 10$ ; $10$ is correct (and is equal to $0 \bmod 5$), but $2$ ? (Also, $r=2 \vee 10$ is bad notation; you really have to write "$r=2$ or $10$".)

Comment: @TonyK Thank you for you reply. I can't see when ${5(d^2 + 2)}$ (mod 5) should equal a square? If we divide ${5(d^2 + 2)}$ by 5, we have ${d^2 + 2}$ which will give us a square + 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write the sum of six consecutive squares as
$$\sum_{i=-2}^3(d+i)^2=6d^2+6d+19=n^2.$$
Then $n$ is odd, say $n=2m+1$, and we have
$3(d^2+d+3)=2m^2+2m.$
But this equates an odd number to an even number, and so no such $n$ can exist.

Your reasoning is correct for the other cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Of six consecutive numbers, three are even and three are odd. The square of the even numbers are congruent to $0$ mod $4$; the squares of the odds are congruent to $1$ mod $4$. Consequently the sum of six consecutive squares is congruent to $3$ mod $4$, which cannot be a square.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really clever way of looking at it!

Answer (score 1):

here's  an expansion of my comment:

$$0+a\equiv a\pmod r$$ means that since $$a=b^2\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$$ we can ignore the $a\equiv 0\pmod 4$ because they don't change the remainders modulo 4.

By similar logic, since the square they sum to $n^2$ has the same remainder possibilities modulo 4,  we get that the number of $a\equiv 1\pmod 4$ that exist, must be $$c\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$$   and since the number of $a\equiv 1\pmod 4$, is also $$\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor$$ or  $$\lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil$$ we know one of these must be congruent to $c$ .

If we take $k=4,5,6$ we have $2$ for the first form for the first 2 of those, and $3$ for the last, or we get $2,3,3$ and all these values aren't congruent to $c$, so they don't work in $k$. In fact adding 8 to $k$ results in the same remainder for the fractions so all $k\equiv 4,5,6\pmod 8$ are out. The only case spared is $k=3$ but with 1 odd value which was previously ruled out.  So we are Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you explanation! Truly helpful!

Comment: Thanks, I don't get that a lot.